# httpd not reading the document root in conf/httpd.conf as expected

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, centos, httpd.conf

I have a Laravel project on my CentOS7 server which sits on the folder "/var/www/html/myProject".

I have changed my document root in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to "/var/www/html/myProject/public" both in "DocumentRoot" and in the directory configure so when i enter the IP in the browser it will automatically show the project.

When i try to do so and access my IP through the browser i am greeted with the messages:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /form on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

After further examination i have found out that in my /var/log/httpd/error_log i get the following error after every access attempt:

> [Thu May 10 19:39:33.683522 2018] [core:crit] [pid 1994] (13)Permission denied: [client 79.182.62.1:51091] AH00529: /var/www/html/myProject/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/myProject/' is executable

That was very odd to me since the path is supposed to be /var/www/html/myProject/public, but the "public" is missing.

I have restarted my apache several times, and changed the DocumentRoot path to a fictional path just to check if it updates and it is.

Could it maybe be something in the .htaccess file? although i didn't change the file, i left it as Laravel created it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on `/var/www/html/myProject` files & directories. Based on the error you pasted it seems apache is attempting to read in data from your `myProject` directory as directed by the .htaccess file. This is normal operation.

Figure out what user/group your apache is running is. Then remember that your files have to be readable that user and all parent directories have to be accessible (hint: execute bit) for that user.

Finally check the bootstrap/cache and storage laravel directories (& subdirectories) are writeable by the apache user.

Comment: Everything is owned by apache, but that's still not the issue. for some reason even though in conf/httpd.conf there is clearly a DocumentRoot of /var/www/html/myProject/public i am still getting errors related to /var/www/html/myProject/.htaccess instead of /var/www/html/myProject/public/.htaccess